# How can I go to a farther page (e.g., page 300) of this single-page site that there's no way to change the URL address to my desired page?

Tags: browser, website

[image: Single-Page Website (blurred content)]

I have to click through the last page many times just to reach a farther page (e.g., page 300). If I close the site and want to visit page 300, I'll have to click the last page again many times.

Comment: Depending on the browser, not full URL may be visible. Have you clicked on the URL to check if there is page number?

Comment: @pbies yes I did, I'm in page 9, I clicked the URL bar, but it's just the domain name showing. no "../page=9" or something.

Comment: Then the only option will be JavaScript in console.

Comment: I'll open developer tools > console?

Comment: Yes. And there look for two things: 1. what happens (messages) when the page is switched to next one 2. which files/functions are called to switch the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to make that a single page website works as multiple page website.

One way is that the site listen for buttons clicks, depending on the button clicked it will make a request to pull data from the server. Another way is that all the data is downloaded as a JSON file when loading the file and clicking the button reads the updates the displayed content based on the JSON file data.

You need to spend some time learning to use the developer tools of your web browser as well HTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM among other stuff required to understand how that website works.